# How to make the animation go slower SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've implemented an image with a rotating animation along with three buttons to adjust the rotation speed. The speed is controlled by modifying the animation duration. However, I'm facing an issue where attempting to slow down the animation results in it continuously speeding up instead.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rotationAngle: Angle = .degrees(0)
    @State var imageSpeed  : Double = 1.5
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("j")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .rotationEffect(rotationAngle, anchor: .center)
                .onChange(of: imageSpeed){ _ in
                    rotationAngle = .degrees(0)
                    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: imageSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    withAnimation(animation) {
                        
                        rotationAngle = .degrees(360)
                        
                    }
                    print(imageSpeed)
                }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                    imageSpeed = 4
                }) {
                    Text("Slow")
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    imageSpeed = 1
                }) {
                    Text("Fast")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    imageSpeed = 0.0
                }) {
                    Text("Stop")
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I gave the code above a try, but it didn't produce the expected result. I would really appreciate any help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the previous animation when starting a new one.  One easy way to do this is to start with a new instance of the `Image`.  By adding an `.id()` to the image, you can start a new instance by changing the `id`.

Below, I have introduced an `@State private var imageid` that tracks the current `id`.  When the `imageSpeed` changes, increment the `imageid` and it will start a new instance using the current new `imageSpeed`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rotationAngle: Angle = .degrees(0)
    @State var imageSpeed  : Double = 1.5
    @State private var imageid = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("j")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .rotationEffect(rotationAngle, anchor: .center)
                .id(imageid)
                .onChange(of: imageSpeed){ _ in
                    imageid += 1
                    rotationAngle = .degrees(0)
                    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: imageSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    withAnimation(animation) {
                        
                        rotationAngle = .degrees(360)
                        
                    }
                    print(imageSpeed)
                }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                    imageSpeed = 4
                }) {
                    Text("Slow")
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    imageSpeed = 1
                }) {
                    Text("Fast")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    imageSpeed = 0.0
                }) {
                    Text("Stop")
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Alternate Solution

Since then change in `imageSpeed` triggers the need for a new image animation, we could have simply added:

```
.id(imageSpeed)
```

to the `Image` eliminating the need to introduce another `@State` variable.